# Transforming a hamburger icon fails

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

for some reason I can't make my hamburger icon work as expected. I have saw many ways of doing it but I can't figure out what's wrong with mine. this is the result I get:

[image]
[image]

I expect to get the 'X' of course.

```css
.hamb span {
  background-color: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 5px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.hamb:hover span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.hamb:hover span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.hamb:hover span:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateX(30px);
  opacity: 0;
}

.hamb:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-item icon">
  <div class="hamb"><span></span> <span></span> <span></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: for one moment i was reading this *Transforming a hamburger fails* .. I was wondering to what you will transform a hamburger ..

Comment: I think you should play with transform-origin property: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp

Comment: share the code of the hamburger icon

Comment: @TemaniAfif sorry my mistake. updated the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add some translation to the first and last span:

```css
.hamb {
 margin:10px;
}

.hamb span {
  background-color: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 5px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.hamb:hover span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(21px);
}
.hamb:hover span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(-21px);
}
.hamb:hover span:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateX(30px) ;
  opacity: 0;
}

.hamb:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="hamb">
 <span></span>
 <span></span>
 <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks that looks much better. but there is a way to make it perfectly match by the pixel? @Temani Afif

Comment: maybe: .hamb:hover span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(-23px);
}

Comment: @hindi1991 yes, adjust the pixel, try 21px

Comment: The  spans's are moving a bit left in order to rotate as they should. Is there a way to avoid this? so they rotate from the spot? @TemaniAfif

Comment: @hindi1991 I think it's an illusion because the middle one is moving

Answer (score 2):

Building on @TermaniAfif's nice answer, I find it nice if the middle line stays in place and X is center aligned:

```css
.hamb span {
  background-color: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 5px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.hamb:hover span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(10px) translateX(11px);
}
.hamb:hover span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(-10px) translateX(11px);
}
.hamb:hover span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

.hamb:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="hamb">
 <span></span>
 <span></span>
 <span></span>
</div>
```