# Responsive SVG viewBox

Tags: html, css, svg

I made a "hamburger button" in SVG, as seen below.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

svg#ham-btn {
  margin: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  fill: #383838;
}
```

```html
<svg id="ham-btn" width="107.5px" height="80px" viewBox="0 0 80 80" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
    #ham-btn {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    #ham-btn:hover #r1 {
      outline: 1px solid transparent;
      transition: transform 0.2s;
      transform-origin: 50% 50%;
      transform: rotate(37deg) translate(0%, 28.75%) scaleX(1.1);
    }
    #ham-btn:hover #r2 {
      transition: transform 0.2s;
      transform: translate(120%, 0);
    }
    #ham-btn:hover #r3 {
      outline: 1px solid transparent;
      transition: transform 0.2s;
      transform-origin: 50% 50%;
      transform: rotate(-37deg) translate(0%, -28.75%) scaleX(1.1);
    }
    
  </style>
  <rect id="r3" x="0" y="71.25%" width="100%" height="15%" rx="5%" />
  <rect id="r2" x="0" y="42.5%" width="100%" height="15%" rx="5%"/>
  <rect id="r1" x="0" y="13.75%" width="100%" height="15%" rx="5%" />
</svg>
```

**Question**

Right now, if I want to make the button smaller, I have to manually make the dimensions of the viewport and `viewBox` smaller by the same amount of px.

Is there any way to make that more responsive? For instance, by making `viewBox` be a percentage of the viewport?

[According to the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute), it seems `viewBox` has to be a `<number>`, and thus cannot be a percentage.

Any thoughts?

Thank you.

---

**Note 1**

I have not added any accessibility or other features to the button. This question is about its responsiveness.

---

**Note 2**

I know I can make the SVG viewport a percentage of its container / the browser viewport.

That does not solve my issue unfortunately, as to make this button work my viewBox-to-viewport ratio must stay fixed (otherwise the button looses its shape).

Thus, I wanted to make the `viewBox` be a percentage of the viewport.

In case it is of interest, my solution takes advantage of the following:

- `viewBox` is wider than viewport, but has the same height
- Thus, `preserveAspectRatio` is used to horizontally center the `rect`s
- `rect` dimensions are in percentage of `viewBox`

The `outline` is to fix a Firefox issue with jagged lines after transform.

---

**Edit:**

In case helpful to future visitors, the final button, including full accessibility, can be found here: https://codepen.io/magnusriga/pen/KrrJKa

Comment: I would remove the width and height of the svg element. Then in CSS I would made SVG's `width:50%`. You don't need a declaration for the height unless you need to squish / stretch the image.

Comment: not intrested in a pure CSS solution ? like this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53555133/how-can-i-let-my-hamburger-animation-reverse/53555325#53555325 or this one :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53270861/transforming-a-hamburger-icon-fails/53270909#53270909

Comment: Hi @TemaniAfif. Thanks for the links. I also previously implemented the menu in HTML+CSS, but recently dived into SVG (as you know) and find it incredibly powerful for graphics and animations. In my opinion, for the hamburger menu, SVG feels like an easier and less hacky approach, compared to HTML+CSS with absolute elements.

Comment: I now just have to understand why setting width / height of the SVG in CSS is not the same as specifying it on the svg's presentation attributes themselves (like I thought the spec said).

Comment: @enxaneta The initial value of the width / height presentation attributes on the SVG element, is 100% (of parent container) if I understand correctly. Removing the height, will break the difference in width / height ratio between the SVG Viewport and the viewBox, which the centering in the viewport depends on (it uses preserveAspectRatio).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add width & height properties to your svg css. With width set and height auto.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

svg#ham-btn {
  margin: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  fill: #383838;
  /* percentage of viewport - height will autocalculate */
  width: 7vw;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<svg id="ham-btn" width="107.5px" height="80px" viewBox="0 0 80 80" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
    #ham-btn {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    #ham-btn:hover #r1 {
      transition: transform 0.2s;
      transform-origin: 50% 50%;
      transform: rotate(37deg) translate(0%, 28.75%) scaleX(1.1);
    }
    #ham-btn:hover #r2 {
      transition: x 0.2s;
      x: 120%;
    }
    #ham-btn:hover #r3 {
      transition: transform 0.2s;
      transform-origin: 50% 50%;
      transform: rotate(-37deg) translate(0%, -28.75%) scaleX(1.1);
    }
    
  </style>
  <rect id="r3" x="0" y="71.25%" width="100%" height="15%" rx="5%" />
  <rect id="r2" x="0" y="42.5%" width="100%" height="15%" rx="5%"/>
  <rect id="r1" x="0" y="13.75%" width="100%" height="15%" rx="5%" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Hi. I know I can make the svg viewport a percentage of its container. I was thinking about the viewBox.

Comment: @Magnus any specific reason why change viewBox attribute in HTML/SVG? Afaik, there are no means to change that via CSS, but JS might help there, although not necessary. You can achieve desired effect (if I understood correctly) by setting width/height.

Comment: If you change the width/height of the viewport without changing the `viewBox`, the button looses its shape. I just added some notes to the OP, that explains how my solution works.

Comment: PS: The black box around the hamburger (the viewport) should be in the exact same % distance from the rects, at any container size. So, if you make it slimmer the way you did, the whole svg looses its shape. The black box (viewport) and the hamburger belongs together. The cross neatly points to the corners of that black box (the viewport), when you hover over.

Comment: @Magnus I've updated answer - added `height: auto` This should preserve the aspect ratio.

Comment: I thought setting svg width / height in CSS would overwrite the SVG viewports own width / heigth (107.5px and 80px). Does it not do that?

Comment: Also, any idea why the edges look jagged after transforming, for about 0.5s, in Firefox? The same thing does not happen in chrome.

Comment: @Magnus yes. CSS properties would "overwrite" HTML default attributes.

Comment: I do not think it is overwriting the svg viewport dimensions of 107.5px and 80px, though? If you try to manually change those, without changing the viewBox, you will see that the shape looses its form.

Comment: I fixed the Firefox issues.

Comment: I think I understand why your solution works. It is because the explicitly set viewport width and height is only used to define an intrinsic aspect ratio different from what viewBox would set (if no width / height was explicitly stated). The actual viewport width and height are then overwritten by CSS, but the svg intrinsic aspect ratio is maintained (107.5 / 80). That aspect ratio is then used when indicating `height: auto` in CSS. Had we not specified auto in CSS, the height would fall back to 80px, as set by the svg. If that is correct, could you please add that explanation to your answer?

Answer (score 1):

As I've told you in my comment: I would remove the width and height of the svg element. Then in CSS I would made SVG's width:20%. I'm making the SVG's width 50% of the width of the window.

In order to keep the proportions I've putted the "hamburger" inside a `<symbol viewBox="0 0 80 80">`. Of coarse in this case you don't need `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"` anymore.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

svg#ham-btn {
  width: 20%;
  margin:auto;
  top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  fill: #383838;
  position:absolute; 
}
```

```html
<svg id="ham-btn" viewBox="0 0 107.5 80" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
    #ham-btn {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    #ham-btn:hover #r1 {
      outline: 1px solid transparent;
      transition: transform 0.2s;
      transform-origin: 50% 50%;
      transform: rotate(37deg) translate(0%, 28.75%) scaleX(1.1);
    }
    #ham-btn:hover #r2 {
      transition: transform 0.2s;
      transform: translate(120%, 0);
    }
    #ham-btn:hover #r3 {
      outline: 1px solid transparent;
      transition: transform 0.2s;
      transform-origin: 50% 50%;
      transform: rotate(-37deg) translate(0%, -28.75%) scaleX(1.1);
    }
    
  </style>
  <symbol id="s" viewBox="0 0 80 80"> 
  <rect id="r3" x="0" y="71.25%" width="100%" height="15%" rx="5%" />
  <rect id="r2" x="0" y="42.5%" width="100%" height="15%" rx="5%"/>
  <rect id="r1" x="0" y="13.75%" width="100%" height="15%" rx="5%" />
  </symbol>  
  
  <use xlink:href="#s"  width="80" x="13.75"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Interesting solution, establishing another viewport within the outer viewport. I guess another option would be to used a nested svg, instead of symbol, as they both establish a new viewport. Regardless, could you please add an explanation to how all the dimensions hang together, i.e. what each initial and computed values is. My guess is that inner-viewport width/height is 100% (initial) of outer width dimensions, which in turn is 100% of parent container. However, we set width in CSS, so outer svg gets a viewport width of 20%, then it uses the SVG's intrinsic dimension to fill in height. 1/2

Comment: 2/3 .... The intrinsic dimensions (as per the spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/coords.html#SizingSVGInCSS) is equal to viewBox.width / viewBox.height (since we did not specify both viewport width and viewport height as absolute values). Finally, this means that the inner viewport and outer viewport are equal in height / width, and both have an intrinsic aspect ratio of 107.5 / 80, which is used by CSS to calculate height (whose initial value when not specified is auto).

Comment: 3/3 ... All of that means, that we actually do not need the inner viewport that you created. We can just have one viewport (as in OP), keep the viewport width and height to make the intrinsic dimensions 107 / 80, then change the width in CSS as desired and set the height to auto (so it does not fall back to 80px). In that solution, the explicitly set viewport width and height is only used to set an intrinsic dimension different from what viewBox indicates. The actual viewport width and height are overwritten by CSS.