# Is it possible to change svg viewBox value using CSS?

Tags: css

I want to change the svg value of the viewBox using CSS when the window width is 660px.
`viewBox="0 0 230 87" =>  viewBox="0 0 100 87"`.Is it possible to change svg viewBox value using CSS ?

Comment: can you add the svg here? or refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53699098/responsive-svg-viewbox

Comment: as far as i know no

Comment: CSS can’t change attributes. Do you definitely want to change the viewbox as opposed to the dimensions of the viewed image?

Comment: as i understand the css cannot change the viewBox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only change [presentation attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/styling.html#PresentationAttributes) through CSS. `viewBox` is not one of these.

What you can do however is to use `<symbol>` elements to define "views" over the scene.
Indeed, `<symbol>` does have a `viewBox` attribute, so you can use this element to point to the whole scene, and then use one `<use>` element per such "view" and control via CSS when this `<use>` is displayed:

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: yellow;
}
@media (max-width:500px) {
  svg { border-color: green; }
  #small-use { display: block; }
  #big-use { display: none; }
}
@media (min-width:501px) {
  #small-use { display: none; }
  #big-use { display: block; }
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <!-- we wrap the whole scene in one symbol -->
  <symbol id="scene">
    <rect fill="blue" x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500"/>
    <rect fill="red"  x="0" y="0" width="50"  height="50" />
  </symbol>

  <!-- following symbols will define our "views" -->
  <symbol id="small-view" viewBox="0 0 60 60">
    <use href="#scene"/>
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="big-view"   viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <use href="#scene"/>
  </symbol>

  <!-- append all the views, CSS will determine which to display -->
  <use href="#small-view" id="small-use"/>
  <use href="#big-view"   id="big-use"/>
</svg>
<p>Change the window's size to trigger the "change of viewBox"</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change SVG width, you can set `width` property on `svg` tag

```
<svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40">...</svg>
```

or, you can add CSS style on it.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 40 40" style="width:80px; height: 80px">...</svg>
```

If you edit `viewBox`, your SVG shape might be destroyed.